# C++/CLI: read from file with native c++ class

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to include a UI into my project, which is written in native C++. In VS2010 I have added a Windows Forms which reads a .bmp image from a file. The pixels of this image should then be changed (and displayed) to values contained in an int array.
The int array comes from a class (in native c++), which uses normal c++ fstream operations to acquire data from an external file. 
It does not work. Compiler gives me no error, but at runtime the image is not dispayed and i get an error. See the code below:

the constructorn of the class PImage initializes the array by reading from an external file

```
PImage::PImage()//constructor
    {//opening original image
    ifstream OldImage;
    OldImage.open ("image.ppm", ios::in | ios::binary);

    //reading the header of the original image file
     OldImage >> Magic [0] >> Magic [1];

     OldImage >> TotRows >> TotCol >> MaxVal;

         Size = (3 * TotRows * TotCol);
        charImage = new char [Size];

         //reading the image in binary format and storing it in the array of characters
         OldImage.read(charImage, Size);

    OldImage.close();
    }
```

then a method of the same class returns the values of the array:

```
int PImage::ReturnImage(int i)
    {       
        return (int)charImage[i];
    }
```

and this is the Windows Forms code:

```
  private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                  try
      {


         // Retrieve the image.
         image1 = gcnew Bitmap( "image.bmp",true );

         int Size = (image1->Width * image1->Height);

         int ^intImage;
         intImage = gcnew int [Size];


         PImage intPixels;

         int index = 0;

         // Loop through the images pixels to reset color. 
         for ( int x = 0; x < image1->Width; x++ )
         {
            for ( int y = 0; y < image1->Height; y++ )
            {
               Color pixelColor = image1->GetPixel( x, y );
               Color newColor = Color::FromArgb( intPixels.ReturnImage(index), intPixels.ReturnImage(index+1), intPixels.ReturnImage(index+2));
               image1->SetPixel( x, y, newColor );
               index = index+3; 

            }

         }

         // Set the PictureBox to display the image.
         pictureBox1->Image = image1;

         // Display the pixel format in Label1.
         label1->Text = String::Format( "Image Width: {0}", image1->Width );
      }


      catch ( ArgumentException^ ) 
      {
         MessageBox::Show( "There was an error." 
         "Check the path to the image file." );
      }
         }
    };
```

note that if i manually write the values of the array this way:

```
int PImage::ReturnImage(int i)
{       
    charImage[i] = 100;
    return (int)charImage[i];
}
```

the debugger catches the problem as follows:
in istream:

```
if (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, extract characters
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->sbumpc();
        if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta))
            _State |= ios_base::eofbit | ios_base::failbit; // end of file
        else
            _Ch = _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta); // got a character
        _CATCH_IO_(_Istr)
        }
```

in particular it flags this line: _Ch = _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta);
saying that _Ch is unidentified value.

the program works and i have a gray image displayed properly. I have the feeling there is something wrong with the PImage class constructor reading information from the image.

Any help/comment/advice would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Error messages are meant to be informative and tell you what is wrong with your program or machine.  Maybe it doesn't mean anything to you.  But clearly it would be wise to mention what it says when you ask a question about it.

Comment: ok sorry about that. I have edited my post so it shows the complete windows forms function. the error I get says "There was an error." 
         "Check the path to the image file.", which comes from the argument exception as shown at the bottom of the windows forms function.

Comment: That's self-inflicted pain.  If you have to catch it then at least display the Exception::Message property, not "There was an error".  That's meaningless, we don't know what that means either.

Comment: ok sorry again. I have removed that message and then ran the debugger. I have edited the code above to show at the end what the debugger says. thanks heaps for taking the time to check on this